# rqt_gui_py.plugin PushButton event error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all.

I have designed a very basic gui in QT5 designer. It consists of some pushbuttons. One of them has the quit event (name = quit).

```
void awc_gui::on_quit_clicked()
{
    qApp->quit();
}
```

This gui works fine in Qt5, but when I export the .ui file to my ~/catkin_ws/src/rqt_awc/resource$ folder

I can load the plugin in rqt, however the event doest work.
I have been taken a look at some examples and I have tried the following in my plugin.py file

```
   self._widget.quit.click.connect(self._on_quit_click)
   def _on_quit_click(self):
       self._widget.quit.quit()
```

I open the rqt after I have compiled the package with catkin_make in the catkin working space.
Then I get the following error:

```
 self._widget.quit.click.connect(self._on_quit_click)
                                                 ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

To be sincere I have no clue, any help will be appreciate it, and in advance thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76099/rqt_gui_py.plugin-pushbutton-event-error/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got it work, I just have followed the plugin example in: https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/blob/hydro-devel/rqt_robot_steering/src/rqt_robot_steering/robot_steering.py The tutorials are good but still they are missing some things, and definitely they can be improved.  So as a beginner I recommend to follow the tutorial and use the robot.steering.py as an example and qt designer to create the .ui

---

Originally posted by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) with karma: 556 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0